# Is this a surjection? Why or why not?

Tags: function, statistics, probability, discrete-mathematics

[image]

I was under the impression that a surjection could exist if |B| > |A|, but I'm not too sure. Can't something like this happen?

Comment: This is not the math SE. Ask here: http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: BTW, the answer is no, since it's not a function en therefore not a surjection.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question again, and I thought I'd give a more complete answer.

Functions `f: X -> Y` must by definition obey the rule that for each `x` in `X` there is only one `y` in `Y` such that `f(x) = y`. Your example does not obey this, and therefore is not a function. It follows that it cannot be a surjection.

Your example should be called a *relation*, rather than a *function*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the function is indeed surjective. As long as for every member of your codomain there exists a member in your domain that maps onto it, the function is surjective. A unique member is not a requirement.

Although incomplete, ive always found http://mathsguide.org/surjections.php to be a decent resource for some of these basics.

Comment: You are wrong, since a function must have only one function value for each domain value.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a function, because you can't have an input pointing to two different results in the codomain